# how do i repeatedly multiply a number in java by 2 until it reaches 1 million?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while, multiplication

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testNumber = userInput.nextInt();
        do{
             System.out.println(newNumber * 2);
             newNumber++;
        }while( testNumber < 1000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: `newNumber *= 2;` `System.out.println(newNumber);`

Comment: Note that you can write `1_000_000` instead of `1000000` for better readability (since Java 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea with your loop, but you have multiple problems with your variables.

1. Your first problem is that you read in a variable from the user - `testNumber`, but then you are (incorrectly) manipulating a completely **different** variable - `newNumber`.
2. Your second problem is that you are testing the **unchanged** variable as your stop condition.

You probably want your loop to be something like:

```
    do {
         testNumber = testNumber * 2;
         System.out.println(testNumber);
    } while(testNumber < 1000000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the number after you multiply it by 2:

```
newNumber = newNumber * 2;
System.out.println(newNumber);
```

Also you are using `newNumber` and `testNumber` and `newNumber` doesn't appear to be defined anywhere...

```
}while( ***testNumber***newNumber*** < 1000000);
```

You need to pick one because if you are updating `newNumber` but comparing `testNumber` in your loop you will have created an infinite loop.

The code you have shown shouldn't compile unless you are leaving something out of your post.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a recursive method for it.

```
public int reachMillion(int num) {
  if(num<=0)
    return -1;          // indicating it is not possible.
  if(num>=1000000)      // Base Condition denoting we have reached 1 million 
    return num;
  return reachMillion(num*2); // recursive part to multiply by 2 until we reach 1 million
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Main {
private static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int newNumber = 0;

    do{
       System.out.println("Enter a positive number: ");

       try{
          newNumber = userInput.nextInt();
       }catch(Exception ignored){  }

       System.out.println("");

    }while(newNumber <= 0);

    System.out.println("-----  " + newNumber + "  multiply by 2 ------");

    while(newNumber <= 1_000_000){
         System.out.print("2 * " + newNumber +" = ");
         newNumber <<= 1;//in some compilers left shift is faster than multiply           
         System.out.println(newNumber);
    }

}
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't help the asker understand why their code doesn't work, nor why yours does.

Comment: Note that there is also the compound-assignment operator `<<=`. So you could do `newNumber <<= 1;`.

Comment: I'd be careful with statements like `<< 1` being faster than `* 2`. It also heavily depends on compiler and CPU optimization.

Answer (score 1):

[@brso05 has done well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281853/3939277) describing what went wrong here. I'd like to offer a complete example:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Main {

    private static Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please input a number: ");

        int userInputNumber = userInputScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        int newNumber = userInputNumber;

        while (newNumber < 1_000_000) {
            newNumber *= 2; // Take the variable on the left, multiply it by the number on the right, and save it in the variable on the left
            System.out.println(newNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDBTsJAEL33KyacitECHkU@gIPGBG/GmCksMLCdNruzRWL49jqlrSDKS3aTnX3z3pvZYIl3m8W2qiLKitwJbLSSBCGbzObIbNw4UhQhtTSHuUXv4QmJ4SuKQFE4KlEMeEFRQtsDwRs35SJIV5gAm133Hc/2XkyWEPfHrUyj36qUOS0gU5d4Jo549fYO6Fa@r6bQolXIgyQagSXuvViD3gDVroDAIUuNe4BeZ1FDiadoz0eGJrsMm7D5lKlqaus1P8vxpbAO@FeyqZwxd2uyBuIT@RFGH8PhsD7nA9Y4kW4mcD@GwQBecWtA1gZKdISpSuV8fFuzlFvIghUq7B5IIN0fP5pFdDRHq7XykBfgsTQ1j/iq4K80/6zgJ@DZpg5Rcx@iqhp9Aw)

---

**Beware!** That code does not handle any bad user input. For instance, if you give it `0`, it will loop forever, and if you give it `foo`, it will crash. In case you want to handle all the edge cases of user input, this will do that:

```
import java.util.*;



public class Main {

    private static Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int userInputNumber;

        // 
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Please input a number: ");
            if (userInputScanner.hasNext()) {
                // The user gave us something, but we don't know if it's a number

                String rawUserInput = userInputScanner.next();

                try {
                    userInputNumber = Integer.parseInt(rawUserInput);

                    // If that previous line runs, the user has given us an integer!
                    System.out.println();
                    if (userInputNumber > 0) {
                        // The user has given a valid number. Break out of the loop and multiply it!
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        // The user has given a bad number. Tell them why and ask again.
                        System.out.println("The number has to be greater than 0.");
                    }
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                    // The user has given us something, but it wasn't an integer
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("That is not a number: " + exception.getMessage());
                }
            }
            else {
                // There is no input, so we can't do anything.
                return;
            }
        }
        // Done looping through user input

        int newNumber = userInputNumber;

        while (newNumber < 1_000_000) {
            newNumber *= 2; // Take the variable on the left, multiply it by the number on the right, and save it in the variable on the left
            System.out.println(newNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVVNb5tAEL3zKya@BKcJcSL1UpoeqrZSDokqJT1VVbXYY9h4vYt2Bxyr8m93ZgEbx4DSqitZgt3lvTdvPvwkSnHxNFtst4Fc5sYSPPFOVJBU0Vkc8MqLRMkpTJVwDu6E1PAnCIBXbmUpCMGRIL7wMBVao4XCob3VeUG7jRvQuNodhw9rR7iMpB7HDUyN36CURs5gySzhA1mp05@/QNjUjXekfklNLct9sUzQxu3p5SXsn1eZVBiSLdADwMFqZJiCIo5DUzj6rlA4ZHAGBQG6wv0AI9Z5@KGcQ3gcYpQJd4/PFI6PaRpBjxlWiiEVpX8CZ5ZIGcd3DgnTrRBmRp8SLLRZeQpJp24vIuhA1t6AFasfOylsc0eWrjTFnc87G2TXPcL9OvKZWW41YcrgubAO@SU8VDGOg14Y9uB2DpQJ4rLBUhr2QEmNYAvtzvmg8YeNhFSWqL1JQvtUe7KTXtDjHCrdF2wnaU0kn2AyHgj6OGutKgGlUFyhdWIi@GxRLIAVgJlXUShjchbONVwokrlacypPBkkS/3m/5E3vLiou0X8XnYhW8iMq5aUuuTvWlVThFiBS7rloELjH6pFnqkErLjKQIKQcEfEOp1rDJBqN/za67s5U0DSDsE7XN2OXgr4@TzEnaTTg7mkoh/1WdFtPcvcJ53uvLbf/rLZ@s7j0pQNtXg0XeNdGEqVId@icSJEHSfyGQ6/fBuqiNsFizVzPtnN2wA8cnhEc9Mxw3OvKj272LVJhdTzAuzkcuV@MrovfzyXKrCnSrDa/In09vPn/YD9Ohgd5NbwhbC9/hKvfk8nE/46z3l46u4HruApcLLBqyVJYKRKG4rKpWhTnbMJBf0Kyrg6aYm6uWZlmfM83iPNTm@9JPQgYvFEAe4EHia0N3ASbYLudGxO8j66Di6tgEly9AA)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky part of `do-while` loops. In that type of loops, `do` part is executed firstly. For the example below, although the input is already bigger than 1000000, it prints 1000001.

```
public void doWhileLoop() {

    int num = 1000001;
    do {
        System.out.println(num);
        num *= 2;
    } while (num < 1000000);
}
```

Therefore, it will be a good idea to use some guard-clauses (aka, `if-statements`) before doing something in do-while loops. Like,

```
public void doWhileLoop() {

     int num = 1000001;
     if(num >= 1000000) {
        return;
     }
     do {
         System.out.println(num);
         num *= 2;
     } while (num < 1000000);
}
```

Comment: Why not just a `while` loop, then?

Comment: I just want to show, how to do with `do-while loop`.